# The StatusLabel is cut when width of another StatusLabel is changed (problem with the Spring property)

Tags: winforms, statusstrip

I have four items in my StatusStrip:

1. StatusLabel with dynamic width
2. StatusLabel with Spring property set to True (to fill the remaining space)
3. StatusLabel with dynamic width
4. a custom StatusStrip control with fixed with

The second one is there because I want to align the last two items to the right, and it will do that (found it on SO).

When I change the text of the first StatusLabel, it will correctly change the width of it, but then the third StatusLabel gets cut, I don't know why...

Without changing the text it behaves well:
[image: Good]

But when the text is changed...
[image: Bad]

Probably the width of the spacer StatusLabel (the second one) remains the same, which - I think - shouldn't. What do You think? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Spring` property doesn't always work properly if it isn't on the far right.

See [Probem with StatusStrip...Help needed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/60f67272-e9dc-47d1-80a9-9921631cbecb)